# PHP Nested query results behavior is odd

Tags: php, fetch

This is just an example, it is not my actual code and I realize that mysql is depricated. All the ticky tacky things that people post because they don't know the actual answer has been dealt with.

Now to the question, day 5 and day 4 both have a list of items in the result. What prints out is the the first id in row5, then all of row4, then the rest of row5. What I expect is to list all of row4 for each item in row5. This is for php. Any ideas? Thanks

This is an example of the query used. Both queries pull from the same table, but use different dates updated by $interval. The database columns are (id, symbol, price, close_dt, volume)

```
$closeDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date. ' '.$interval.' days'));
$query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM stock WHERE close_dt ='%s'", 
     mysql_real_escape_string($closeDate));

$day4 = mysql_query($query);


while ($row5 = mysql_fetch_assoc($day5)) {
    echo $row5['id'];
    while ($row4 = mysql_fetch_assoc($day4)) {
         echo $row4['id'];
    }
}
```

Comment: mysql_fetch "consume" datas , i mean : once a row is fetched, it will be removed from the result list.  In your  code, you consume first row of $day5, then all $day4, so the $day4 is empty after the loop, then you loop again to a row $day5, then $day4 (but it is empty...), then on rows $day5, then loop $day4 (but it is empty) etc...

Comment: can you show the contents of $ rows 4 and $ rows 5 with a var_dump ($ row4) and var_dump ($ row 5). (not necessarily everything, but the relevant keys and values)

Comment: @Eric Is there a way to loop result sets like this without querying the database again?

Comment: can you also show the 2 selects (I guess there are 2 ...), because I think that only one select with a join can be more efficient and simpler.

Comment: Also you can see what happens here http://ridestock.com/PHP/search_otcbb.php

Comment: The two selects, pull stocks from a database yesterday for row5 and the day before row 4 and I want to show which stocks went up.

Comment: can you display the structure of both of tables ? and the "selects ..." you have been build ? EDIT : ah ok, it is the same table ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200581/discussion-between-user1854438-and-eric).

Answer (score 1):

solution is to use

```
mysql_data_seek($day4,0);
```

example:

```
while ($row5 = mysql_fetch_assoc($day5)) {
    echo $row5['id'];
    mysql_data_seek($day4,0);
    while ($row4 = mysql_fetch_assoc($day4)) {
         echo $row4['id'];
    }
```

}